# Programmatically creating relationships between words in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a neo4j database populated with ~35K english language words.  I want to create relationships between words that differ by a single letter at a given position in the word.  i.e. (a)--(i) or (food)--(fool)  or (cat)--(hat)

For single letter words, the cypher query is pretty simple:

> START n=node(*), m=node(*) where n.name =~ '.' and m.name =~ '.' and
>   NOT (n.name = m.name) create (n)-[:single_letter_change]->(m)

Building relationships for multiletter words is not so simple unfortunately.  I know one can create a collection as in:

> WITH
>   ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']·
>   9 AS letters

and I know one can iterate over a range with:

> FOREACH (i IN range(0,25))

But anything I put together seems to be ugly, messy, and syntactically invalid.  I am confident there is an elegant way to accomplish this in Cypher using the collection functions but I have spent a couple days trying to figure it out and it is time to ask for help.

Ideas for how to accomplish this?  I will be glad to post some of the (invalid) cypher queries I have tried, but I am afraid they might just confuse the issue.

EDIT:
Here is an example of something I tried to set relationships for the first letters of two letter words, but I think it may be off the mark and I know it won't run:

> WITH ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'] AS alphabet FOREACH (first IN range(0,25) | START n=node(*), m=node(*) where n.name =~ (alphabet[{first}] + '.') and m.name =~ (alphabet[{first}] + '.') and NOT (n.name = m.name) create (n)-[:single_letter_change]->(m)

Comment: Probably easier done in a programming language, it would be cool if split(word,"") worked then you could convert a word into an array and work from there. Perhaps storing the letters of a word as an array on the node would help simplify the task?

Comment: Michael, I am probably guilty of premature optimization but my hope was that Cypher could accomplish this more efficiently than could be done via a programming language API.  I am currently running neo4j on my Macbook Air so efficiency is important.

Comment: Michael, doesn't split(word, "") do just that? (e.g. split("Michael", "") yields [M,i,c,h,a,e,l]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could use some refinement but I think it fits the bill

```
// match all the words, start with ones that are three characters long
match (w:Word)
where length(w.name) = 3
// create a collection the length of the matched word
with range(0,length(w.name)-1) as w_len, w
unwind w_len as idx
// iterate through the word and replace one letter at a time
// making a regex pattern
with "(?i)" + left(w.name,idx) + '.' + right(w.name,length(w.name)-idx-1) as pattern, w, w_len
// match the pattern against 3 letter words
// that are not the word
// not already like the word
// and match the pattern
match (new_word:Word)
where not (new_word = w) 
and not((new_word)-[:LIKE]-(w))
and length(new_word.name) = length(w_len)
and new_word.name =~ pattern
// create the relationship
create (new_word)-[:LIKE]->(w)
return new_word, w
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dave.  That is a huge help.  The comments are especially welcome.

Comment: np - was an interesting problem; made we want to fire up my own 35k English word graph!  I think like Michael says there is probably a lot to be gained by using something like this in the structure of a program for optimal flexibility and control.